# SQL Server 2014 Create DDL trigger on Create Table that creates a trigger for the table

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I'm working with a third party tool that creates databases and tables. I would like a trigger on one of those tables being created.  I thought I would try to create a server DDL trigger that fires when the table is created in a new database, which in turn creates a trigger on that table.  I cannot add the trigger to the 'model' database because this table is created via the tool dynamically.

I've tried the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_createTable   
ON ALL SERVER   
FOR CREATE_TABLE   
AS   
    DECLARE @databaseName varchar(255)
    DECLARE @AffectedTables varchar(255) 
    SELECT  @AffectedTables = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') 
    IF (@AffectedTables IN ('DynamicallyCreatedTable'))
    BEGIN

        select @databaseName = CAST(eventdata().query('/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName[1]/text()') as NVarchar(128))

        EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER ' + @databaseName + '.[dbo].[tgrDynamicTableTrigger]
              ON
                ' + @databaseName + '.[dbo].[DynamicallyCreatedTable]
              AFTER UPDATE
              AS
              BEGIN
                SET NOCOUNT ON
                -- trigger code here
              END')
    END
GO
```

Which produces the following error when the table is created;

> Msg 166, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 'CREATE/ALTER TRIGGER' does not
>   allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

I tried changing the dynamic sql by replacing the fully qualified table name to attempt a 'use' statement:

```
--- 8< ---
    EXEC('use ' + @databaseName + '
          CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgrDynamicTableTrigger]
          ON
--- 8< ---
```

However, that produced the following error when the table was created:

> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first
>   statement in a query batch.

Any ideas?

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I would ask why you need that trigger in the first place. Triggers can be useful but often they are not the right tool for the job. This has all the appearance of an xy problem to me. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have figured it out, thanks mostly to this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48161).

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ddl_trig_createTable   
ON ALL SERVER   
FOR CREATE_TABLE   
AS   
    DECLARE @statement nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tgrDynamicTableTrigger]
              ON
                [dbo].[DynamicallyCreatedTable]
              AFTER UPDATE
              AS
              BEGIN
                 -- trigger code here
              END'

    DECLARE @databaseName varchar(255)
    DECLARE @AffectedTables varchar(255) 
    SELECT  @AffectedTables = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') 
    IF (@AffectedTables IN ('DynamicallyCreatedTable'))
    BEGIN

        SET @databaseName = CAST(eventdata().query('/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName[1]/text()') as NVarchar(128))

        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = QUOTENAME(@databaseName) + '.sys.sp_executesql';
        EXEC @sql @statement;

    END
GO
```